# Обработка массива в бесконечном цикле

Tags: python

Есть массив. Выступает он в роли некой "очереди". Нужно как то обрабатывать его в бесконечном цикле, но это нагружаемо, постоянно пытаться проверять, есть ли там что то, можно ли как то делать блокировку, пока в массиве не появится новый элемент, например как recv в сокетах?

Comment: [Посмотрите очереди](https://pymotw.com/2/Queue/) ...

Comment: сделайте вашу очередь классом, в котором добавление вызывает действие, ну и воткните это в ваш  "цикл"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random, time, threading, queue

array = queue.Queue()  # Есть массив. Выступает он в роли некой "очереди".
results = queue.Queue()  # результ

def array_add_items():
    '''добавить эдементы в массив'''
    while True:
        for _ in range(random.randrange(10000)):
            array.put_nowait(random.randrange(10))
        print('len array(%s)' % array.qsize())
        time.sleep(random.randrange(5)) 

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    '''Нужно как то обрабатывать его в бесконечном цикле'''
    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                # можно ли как то делать блокировку, пока в массиве не появится новый элемент
                item = array.get(timeout=2)
                results.put(-item)
                array.task_done()
            except queue.Empty:
                print('timeout=2 : array({i})->results({o})'.format(i=array.qsize(), o=results.qsize()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WorkerThread().start()
    array_add_items()
```

out:

```
len array(2042)
timeout=2 : array(0)->results(9860)
len array(1080)
len array(139)
timeout=2 : array(0)->results(12729)
len array(1273)
len array(1802)
len array(640)
timeout=2 : array(0)->results(32977)
len array(1137)
```